# How to split a long javascript file into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, firebase, visual-studio-code

I have a long JavaScript file with length around 57K lines of code!
It serves the purpose of a Firebase function.

Is there any way to auto split it into smaller files and functions?

like through vsCode or some kind of little known extension?

What options do I have aside from manually editing it?

Thanks

Comment: It is code? Or it is like data? Unclear what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, code. It's a file that has at least 200 functions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it all by hand, took two days and a lot of boredom; but it was doable.

The right solution is in my opinion is to build some kind of parser/AST to read the javascript file, tokenize it, then split it based on some rules.

I hope somebody could provide a POC for this in the future, or maybe even a library author builds one, generic enough to support this use-case.